# why string interning and number interning is different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

When I compare id of a and b as following it returns true

```
a = 5
b = 5
print(a is b) # prints true 

a = 5
b = 4
b += 1
print(a is b) # prints true
```

but when I use do the same thing with the string it returns false

```
s1 = 'string'
s2 = 'strin'
s2 += 'g'
print(s1 is s2) # returns false
```

Comment: Because interning is implementation-defined and you shouldn't rely on it.  It's just an optimization and up to the implementation what is interned.

Comment: Why would they be the same? For the `int` case, for example, this is the corollary of the small-int cache, since 5 falls into the small int range.

Comment: https://python-tutorials.in/python-is-operator/   See especially the summary at the bottom describing usage of `is` vs. `==`.

Comment: CPython interns 260 or so `int` values. That's less by several orders of magnitude than even the number of single-character `str` values. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805768/what-are-the-rules-for-cpythons-string-interning.

Comment: Interning requires the implementation, *every* time a new value is created, to check if the value was already created. Most interning decisions are based on the question of when is creating a new value less expensive than the overhead of finding an existing value.

Comment: as far as I understood, it depends on the implementation of python whether or not to intern or not and these values. and implementation decisions are made considering tradeoff of the time and memory.